# Allowing anonymous users to upload to a specific Imgur account using Imgur api?

Tags: php, image, api, oauth-2.0, imgur

I'm trying to build a web application which will allow many users to upload images to the same album on my own Imgur account.

Is this possible without the need for authorization from the anonymous user?

From the Api documentation on OAuth2 https://api.imgur.com/oauth2 it basically states the user gets redirected so that they can authorize the app by inputting their password.

Is it only possible when using an anonymous album? Or not at all?