# Imgur API upload to specific account

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, imgur

So I essentially want to upload images to a specific imgur account using the Imgur API without needing to go through the whole oAuth process. I'm currently doing this using google scripts but it's not really language-specific.

Its the same question as this: [Allowing anonymous users to upload to a specific Imgur account using Imgur api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046641/allowing-anonymous-users-to-upload-to-a-specific-imgur-account-using-imgur-api)

Since this post was so old I figured I would re-upload it and see if anyone has found the answer.